# Filling a polygon with a texture (or a color) C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to figure how to put a texture or fill a "DrawPolygon" with a simple color in C# Visual Studio (using right now 2015).

```
 //Left Wall 1
 Point lw1a = new Point(18, 7); 
 Point lw1b = new Point(99, 61); 
 Point lw1c = new Point(99, 259); 
 Point lw1d = new Point(18, 313);

 Point[] lw1 = { lw1a, lw1b, lw1c, lw1d };

 gr.DrawPolygon(pen, lw1);`
```

This is a example code for one of the things I'm drawing on screen. Any idea on how I can achieve that? 
Thanks!

Comment: The programmers over at Stack Overflow would probably know more about this then us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [Graphics.FillPolygon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89sks199(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example :

```
            // Create solid brush.
            SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

            // Create points that define polygon.
            Point lw1a = new Point(18, 7); 
            Point lw1b = new Point(99, 61); 
            Point lw1c = new Point(99, 259); 
            Point lw1d = new Point(18, 313);
            Point[] lw1 = { lw1a, lw1b, lw1c, lw1d };

            // Define fill mode.
            FillMode newFillMode = FillMode.Winding;

            // assuming gr a graphic object
            gr.FillPolygon(blueBrush, lw1 , newFillMode);
```

For using a texture you can try [TextureBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.texturebrush(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of SolidBrush

Follow example filling ellipse with texture :

```
 try
    {
        Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\" +
            @"All Users\Documents\My Music\music.bmp", true);

        TextureBrush texture = new TextureBrush(image1);
        texture.WrapMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile;
        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(texture, 
            new RectangleF(90.0F, 110.0F, 100, 100));
        formGraphics.Dispose();

    }
    catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
            "Please check the path.");
    }
```

Comment: One thing (sorry for the question), but... how I use FillPolygonPointFFillMode? I mean, I don't understand what parameters or arguments I need to introduce when I call it (FillPolygonPointFFillMode(); for example). I'm a little new in C# and I don't know many things yet. Thanks for everything.

Comment: this is an example method.. consider only the body. I edited the example considering your piece of code